# Open Apple Fitness App on iPhone via Deeplink

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm looking for a deeplink or URL Scheme to open Apples Fitness app on iPhone. I would like to open the view of a specific workout recorded via `HealthKit`. Does anybody know of a deeplink or equivalent solution?